# Unable to change markersize while using plt.scatter with three variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I am plotting z (binary) on a grid (x-y) data using following code:

plt.scatter(x,y,z, color='c', marker= 'o')

The result works fine. But I wish to increase the markersize in the same code. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the marker size using the `s` keyword argument, like so:

```
plt.scatter(x,y,z, color='c', marker= 'o', s=100)
```

A full example:

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#make some data similar to your description
a = np.linspace(0.,5.,10)
x,y = np.meshgrid(a,a)
z = np.random.randint(low=0,high=2,size=100).reshape(10,10)

#plot in 3D with s=100
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x,y,z,marker='o',s=100)

#or plot in 2D and colour the points by z (sometimes easier to look at than 3d)
fig1,ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.scatter(x,y,c=z,marker='o',s=100,cmap="Blues")
```

This produces the following plots:

[image]

[image]